# Videos recorded in Record RTC on Chrome do not play on Safari

Tags: javascript, webrtc, video.js, video-recording, recordrtc

I'm trying to record videos using the RecordRTC library but the issue is that videos recorded in Chrome Macbook do not play in

-Safari Macbook+iPhone
-Chrome iPhone

This is the source code using the [RecordRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC) and the serie of testings[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gc5yk.png)

```
var startCameraBtn = document.querySelector('#start-camera-btn');
var startRecordingBtn = document.querySelector('#start-recording-btn');
var stopRecordingBtn = document.querySelector('#stop-recording-btn');
var retakeRecordingBtn = document.querySelector('#retake-recording-btn');
var saveRecordingBtn = document.querySelector('#save-recording-btn');
var publishJobBtn = document.querySelector('#publish-job-btn');
var video = document.querySelector('video');

var recorder; // globally accessible
var blob;
var mimeType;  // "video/webm;codecs=vp9";
var videoFormat; //webm

check_user_browser();

function captureCamera(callback) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true }).then(function(camera) {
        callback(camera);
        console.log("Camera started");
    }).catch(function(error) {
        alert('Unable to capture your camera. Please check console logs.');
        console.error(error);
    });
}

function stopRecordingCallback() {
    video.src = video.srcObject = null;
    video.muted = false;
    video.volume = 1;
    blob = recorder.getBlob()
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    
    //recorder.camera.stop();
    //recorder.destroy();
    //recorder = null;
}



function startCamera(){
    this.style.display = "none";
    saveRecordingBtn.style.display = "none";
    startRecordingBtn.style.display = "block";
    
    captureCamera(function(camera) {
        video.muted = true;
        video.volume = 0;
        video.srcObject = camera;

        recorder = RecordRTC(camera, {
            type: 'video',

            // audio/webm
            // audio/webm;codecs=pcm
            // video/mp4
            // video/webm;codecs=vp9
            // video/webm;codecs=vp8
            // video/webm;codecs=h264
            // video/x-matroska;codecs=avc1
            // video/mpeg -- NOT supported by any browser, yet
            // audio/wav
            // audio/ogg  -- ONLY Firefox
            // demo: simple-demos/isTypeSupported.html
            mimeType: mimeType,

            // MediaStreamRecorder, StereoAudioRecorder, WebAssemblyRecorder
            // CanvasRecorder, GifRecorder, WhammyRecorder
            recorderType: MediaStreamRecorder,

            // disable logs
            disableLogs: true,

            // get intervals based blobs
            // value in milliseconds
            timeSlice: 1000,

            // requires timeSlice above
            // returns blob via callback function
            ondataavailable: function(blob) {},

            // auto stop recording if camera stops
            checkForInactiveTracks: false,

            // requires timeSlice above
            onTimeStamp: function(timestamp) {},

            // both for audio and video tracks
            bitsPerSecond: 128000,

            // only for audio track
            // ignored when codecs=pcm
            audioBitsPerSecond: 128000,

            // only for video track
            videoBitsPerSecond: 128000,

            // used by CanvasRecorder and WhammyRecorder
            // it is kind of a "frameRate"
            frameInterval: 90,

            // if you are recording multiple streams into single file
            // this helps you see what is being recorded
            previewStream: function(stream) {},

            // used by CanvasRecorder and WhammyRecorder
            // you can pass {width:640, height: 480} as well
            video: HTMLVideoElement,

            // used by CanvasRecorder and WhammyRecorder
            canvas: {
                width: 640,
                height: 480
            },

            // used by StereoAudioRecorder
            // the range 22050 to 96000.
            sampleRate: 96000,

            // used by StereoAudioRecorder
            // the range 22050 to 96000.
            // let us force 16khz recording:
            desiredSampRate: 16000,

            // used by StereoAudioRecorder
            // Legal values are (256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384).
            bufferSize: 16384,

            // used by StereoAudioRecorder
            // 1 or 2
            numberOfAudioChannels: 2,

            // used by WebAssemblyRecorder
            frameRate: 30,

            // used by WebAssemblyRecorder
            bitrate: 128000,

            // used by MultiStreamRecorder - to access HTMLCanvasElement
            elementClass: 'multi-streams-mixer'

        });

      //  alert("video/webm;codecs=h264");

        // release camera on stopRecording
        recorder.camera = camera;
    });
}
function startRecording(){
    this.style.display = "none";
    stopRecordingBtn.style.display = "block";
    recorder.startRecording();
}
function stopRecording(){
    this.style.display = "none";
    retakeRecordingBtn.style.display = "block";
    saveRecordingBtn.style.display = "block";
    recorder.stopRecording(stopRecordingCallback);
}
function saveRecording(){
    this.innerHTML = 'Saving...';
     // generating a random file name
    var fileName = getFileName(videoFormat);

    // we need to upload "File" --- not "Blob"
    var fileObject = new File([blob], fileName, {
         type: 'video/'.videoFormat
    });
    uploadToPHPServer(fileObject, function(response, fileDownloadURL) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
startCameraBtn.onclick = startCamera;
startRecordingBtn.onclick = startRecording;
stopRecordingBtn.onclick = stopRecording;
retakeRecordingBtn.onclick = startCamera;
saveRecordingBtn.onclick = saveRecording;


function uploadToPHPServer(blob, callback) {
    // create FormData
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('video-filename', blob.name);
    formData.append('video-blob', blob);
    callback('Uploading recorded-file to server.');

    var upload_url = 'upload_video.php';
    // var upload_url = 'RecordRTC-to-PHP/save.php';

    var upload_directory = upload_url;
    // var upload_directory = 'RecordRTC-to-PHP/uploads/';
                
    makeXMLHttpRequest(upload_url, formData, function(progress) {
        if (progress !== 'upload-ended') {
            callback(progress);
            return;
        }
        var initialURL = upload_directory + blob.name;
        callback('ended', initialURL);
    });
}

function makeXMLHttpRequest(url, data, callback) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            if (request.responseText === 'success') {
                callback('upload-ended');
                return;
            }
            saveRecordingBtn.innerHTML = request.responseText;
            publishJobBtn.style.display = "block";
            return;
        }
    };
    request.upload.onloadstart = function() {
        callback('PHP upload started...');
    };
    request.upload.onprogress = function(event) {
        callback('PHP upload Progress ' + Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100) + "%");
    };
    request.upload.onload = function() {
        callback('progress-about-to-end');
                };
    request.upload.onload = function() {
        callback('PHP upload ended. Getting file URL.');
    };
    request.upload.onerror = function(error) {
        callback('PHP upload failed.');
    };
    request.upload.onabort = function(error) {
        callback('PHP upload aborted.');
    };
    request.open('POST', url);
    request.send(data);
}

function check_user_browser(){
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') !== -1 ) {
        console.log("Chrome");
        mimeType="video/webm;codecs=vp9";
        videoFormat = "webm";
        console.log("Video format: "+videoFormat+" mimeType: "+mimeType);
    }else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') !== -1 ){
        console.log("Safari");
        mimeType="video/mp4;codecs=h264";
        videoFormat = "mp4";
        console.log("Video format: "+videoFormat+" mimeType: "+mimeType)
    }else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') !== -1 ){
        console.log("Firefox");
        mimeType="video/webm;codecs=vp9";
        videoFormat = "webm";
        console.log("Video format: "+videoFormat+" mimeType: "+mimeType)
    }
}
// this function is used to generate random file name
            function getFileName(fileExtension) {
                var d = new Date();
                var year = d.getUTCFullYear();
                var month = d.getUTCMonth();
                var date = d.getUTCDate();
                return 'RecordRTC-' + year + month + date + '-' + getRandomString() + '.' + fileExtension;
            }

            function getRandomString() {
                if (window.crypto && window.crypto.getRandomValues && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') === -1) {
                    var a = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(3)),
                        token = '';
                    for (var i = 0, l = a.length; i < l; i++) {
                        token += a[i].toString(36);
                    }
                    return token;
                } else {
                    return (Math.random() * new Date().getTime()).toString(36).replace(/\./g, '');
                }
            }
```

cross browser videos playing and recording

Answer (score 2):

Apple's support for WebM is sketchy, and I don't think that the limitations have been documented anywhere.  My (possibly mistaken) understanding is that:

- VP8 is reasonably well supported, but only for WebRTC tracks, not for playing WebM files;
- VP9 is supported for WebRTC tracks on some versions of Safari only;
- WebM is supported on desktop Safari, at least with VP8, perhaps also with VP9 on some versions of Safari;
- iOS Safari does not support WebM at all, whatever the codec.

You therefore have the following solutions:

- record as H.264, which is well-supported across a variety of devices, but might force you to pay a licencing fee;
- record as WebM with the VP8 codec, and require your iOS users to install a third party video viewer (such as vlc);
- continue recording as WebM with VP9, and declare that Safari is not supported due to Apple's hostile stance against patent-free codecs.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have already figured out the solution by implementing the FFMPEG transcoder. All videos recoreded with RecordRTC are transcoded to H264 AAC codecs.

Comment: @nadwebdev, so you kept using "video/mp4;codecs=h264" for Safari and "video/webm;codecs=vp9" for chrome/ff, and then you transcoded both to H264 AAC codecs?